# Issue with sorting item base on select opton with php/jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want that when I select low_high/high_low option that the product change base on price but right now it does not work. The product are showing but with error msg/also the change select option not working

Possible issue - `PHP/JQUERY data-order="' .$_POST["order"]`.

Note the product show correctly if I remove `data-order="' .$_POST["order"]. '"` etc

Getting - Undefined index: order

HTML

```
<?php  include 'sort.php'; ?>

<div class="form-group ml-5">
    <select name="filter" id="filter" class="form-control">
       <option value="ASC">Price - Highest to Lowest</option>
       <option value="DESC">Price - Lowest to Highest</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

sort.php

```
function product_item_details_filter(){

require_once("db.php");
$conn = pdo_con();

$output = '';

$result = stmt_query_filter();

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $prod_id = $row['product_item_id'];

    $output .= '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 mb-4" id="tests" data-order="' .$_POST["order"]. '">' // not sure if id=tests should be here
        . '<div class="card text-white bg-dark" >'; // or here?

    $output .= '<a href="#" data-order="' .$_POST["order"]. '"><img class="card-img-top" src="images/' . $row["product_item_imgpath"] . ' " alt=" ' . $row["product_item_titlename"] . ' "></a>';

    $output .= '<div class="card-body">';


    $output .= '<h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">' . $row["product_item_titlename"] . '</a></h5>

                    <h5>Price: Rs <a class="column_sort disabled" id="item_price" data-order="' .$_POST["order"]. '" href="#" aria-disabled="true" tabindex="-1">' . $row['item_price'] . '</a></h5>

                    <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="' . $row['product_item_titlename'] . '" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="' . $row['item_price'] . '" />

                    <p class="card-text" >' . $row["product_item_description"] . ' </p>
                  </div>';

    $output .= '<div class="card-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-' . $prod_id . '">Details</button>
                        <button id="' . $prod_id . '" name="add_to_cart" class="product_cart btn btn-danger" value="Add to Cart">Add To Cart</button>
                    </div>';

    $output .= ' </div>'
        . '</div>';

    $output .= '<!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-' . $prod_id . '" tabindex="-' . $prod_id . '" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel-' . $prod_id . '">
                  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                      <div class="modal-content">

                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel-' . $prod_id . '">' . $row["product_item_titlename"] . '</h4>
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

                          </div>

                          <div class="modal-body">
                              <img src="images/' . $row['product_item_imgpath'] . '" style="width:65%; border: 5px solid black;" alt="' . $row["product_item_titlename"] . '"/><br/><br/>
                              <strong>Description</strong>: <p class="card-text">' . $row["product_item_description"] . '</p>
                              <strong>Price</strong>: Rs ' . $row['item_price'] . '<br/>
                          </div>

                          <div class="card-footer"><small class="text-muted"></small></div>

                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            ';

}

return $output;
}

?>
```

FORM

```
<div class="row">

        <?php

        require_once("db.php");
        $conn = pdo_con();

        $output = '';

        if(isset($_POST["order"])) {

            if ($order == 'DESC') {
                $order = 'ASC';
            } else {
                $order = 'DESC';
            }
        }

        function stmt_query_filter(){

            $conn = pdo_con();

            $query = 'SELECT * FROM product_items as pi
          INNER JOIN product_category as pc ON pi.item_category_id = pc.item_category_id
          WHERE pc.item_category_id = 4
          ORDER BY pi.item_price '.$_POST["order"].' '; // getting error here

            $result = $heidisql->query($query);

            return $result;
        }

        echo product_item_details_filter();

        ?>

      </div> <!-- END of Row -->
```

JQUERY

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#filter').change(function(){
            var order = $(this).data("order");

            $.ajax({
                url:"sort.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{order:order},
                success:function(data) {
                    $('#tests').html(data);

                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: change option values to "ASC" and "DESC". like that `<option value="ASC">Price - Highest to Lowest</option>` . Also send data like this : `data:JSON.stringify({order:order}`

Comment: getting `undefined index order`, also should I change `var order = $(this).attr("data-order");` like it was say below

Comment: have you tried `if(isset($_POST["order"])){
    //codes here...
 } `

Comment: do you mean like I did above, ok it work but I still get `undefined index:order` on those line `data-order="'.$_POST["order"].'"` and the SQL